# what is the best way to get azure blob storage

Tags: azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-blob-storage, sca

I'm working with scala and spark and need to access azure blob storage and get its list of files. What is the best way to do that knowing spark version is 2.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For Spark running on local, there is an official [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arsen/2016/07/13/accessing-azure-storage-blobs-from-spark-1-6-that-is-running-locally/) which introduces how to access Azure Blob Storage from Spark. The key is that you need to configure Azure Storage account as HDFS-compatible storage in core-site.xml file and add two jars hadoop-azure & azure-storage to your classpath for accessing HDFS via the protocol wasb[s]. You can refer to the official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage) to know HDFS-compatible storage with wasb, and the [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cindygross/2013/04/25/access-azure-blob-stores-from-hdinsight/) about configuration for HDInsight more details.
2. For Spark running on Azure, the difference is just only access HDFS with wasb, the other preparations has been done by Azure when
   creating HDInsight cluster with Spark. The method for listing files
   is [listFiles](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@listFiles():Seq[String]) or [wholeTextFiles](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@wholeTextFiles(path:String,minPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String,String)]) of SparkContext