# What is a faster way to delete files in an Azure blob with Spark?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I am using Databricks/Spark on Azure. I want to delete over 100,000 text files stored in a blob. The blob is mounted. My code to delete these files in a parallelized way using Python (PySpark) is as follows.

```
import os

# use dbutils to list all files
# very slow operation
text_files = ['/dbfs/mnt/myblob/myfolder/{}'.format(fi.name) for fi in dbutils.fs.ls('/dbfs/mnt/myblob/myfolder')]

# use spark context to parallelize list of text files
rdd = sc.parallelize(text_files)

# now delete files
# seems to be very slow as well when spark job kicks off
rdd.map(lambda p: os.remove(p)).count()
```

Note that I am using `dbutils` to list the files in the mounted directory. This operation is slow. Also note that I am using Python's `os.remove(...)` to delete the file, and this operation seems to be slow as well.

Any tips on a faster way to delete files in an Azure blob in the context of Spark/Databricks?

There are also related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331748/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-azure-blob-storage) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022917/azure-blob-parallel-blob-deleting). However, the former does not specify the context/environment (the referenced links are for Scala and those methods do not exist on the Spark context in PySpark) and the latter wants to implement parallel delete but does not say if the solution needs to be with Spark.

Comment: Using spark to do that is probably not the best solution. Just do a `dbutils.rm` on your folder.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are reading data from a distributed file system, then you import them in your python driver, you export them on Spark, and read them again with Python to perform the remove ...

I think you could just remove the spark step, manipulate your list in python and remove the files using `dbutils` directly.

Comment: But that is not a parallel operation.

Comment: just do it in parallel with some libraries made for that ... but not spark. Spark is supposed to deal with data, so you are just deflecting its functionalities. You are not even sure that your data are well distributed among the cluster, maybe, you do not have any parcellisation.

Answer (score 0):

I realise not directly answering your question, but seeing as you are using Azure and likely using Data Factory (or perhaps will be in the future when orchestrating / productionising your data bricks work)...

You may wish to considering the Data Factory delete activity which is a reasonably new addition to data factory v2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/delete-activity

It has the ability to parallelise deletes.

Comment: I would advocate this approach. Spark uses a single core on the driver node to list files in a folder - this is often a problem with importing data too. I'm not sure if dbutils can use parallel threads to delete - but I suspect it doesn't.

Comment: Not acceptable unless we can programmatically specify for Data Factory to delete. Is that possible?

Comment: Hi Jane, yes this is possible. There is a programmatic c# API as well for constructing data factories: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-dot-net

Answer (score 0):

I used the following method (scala) on an Azure Blob Gen2 storage:

The `subMask` contains the structure as created by `partitionBy` during the persistence of the parquet files.

The *mssparkutils.fs.rm(x, **true**)* removes the directory recursively.

```
    val rootPath = "abfss://**@**.dfs.core.windows.net/parquet/poc-out/"
    val subMask = s"/year=$year/month=$month/day=$dayOfMonth/"    

    mssparkutils.fs.ls(rootPath).filter(_.isDir).foreach( r => 
        {
            val sd = s"${r.path}$subMask"
            val pathExists = mssparkutils.fs.exists(sd)
            if(pathExists){
                mssparkutils.fs.rm(sd, true) //remove path + files
            }
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_location="give the file location"
objectName="abc"
listOfFile = dbutils.fs.ls(file_location)
fileNameSamePattern=[]

for file in listOfFile:
  if file.name.startswith(objectName):
    fileNameSamePattern.append(file.name)
print("File List of same pattern",fileNameSamePattern)

#deleting files from blob

for file in fileNameSamePattern:
    source_path = file_location + file
    dbutils.fs.rm(source_path)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**